# ¿Es posible acceder a un atributo static sin usar self:: o NombreClase:: en PHP orientado a objetos?

Tags: php

Teniendo la siguiente clase llamada `Pagina`:

```
    class Pagina
    {

        public $_nombre = "Bienvido a tu casa";
        public static $_url ="tucasa.com";


        public function bienvenida()
        {
            echo $this->_nombre;
            echo "URL:".$this->_url;

        }

        public static function bienvenida2()
        {
            echo "URL:". self::$_url;
        }
    }

$pagina= new Pagina();

$pagina->bienvenida2();
```

---

Esta contiene un atributo del tipo estático (`static`) y para acceder a los atributos `static` debo utilizar un método estático.

---

**Mi pregunta es:**

¿Es posible acceder al atributo estatico `$_url`, sin utilizar directamente la variable con el metodo `self::` , es decir existe otro metodo donde se pueda acceder colocando `_url`? , o solo es posible haciendo uso del `self::` o en este caso `Pagina::` ?

Comment: No entiendo bien la pregunta, pero otra forma es usar `static::$_url`. ¿Quisieras acceder usando algo así como `$var::_url` o `$var->_url`? Por que si es el caso, con ninguna de las dos es posible.

Comment: @Victor Alvarado como quieres usarlo entonces??? algun ejemplo de lo que especulas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En `OOP` hay dos clases de variables:

Las que están definidas a nivel de clase y las que están definidas a nivel de objeto.

Las de clase existen aunque nunca se haya instanciado un objeto de esa clase. 
Esta característica también hace que la variable sea compartida por todos los objetos que se instancien. Si un objeto cambia el valor, ese valor cambia para todos los objetos que la usen.

Las que están a nivel de objeto, se crean cuando se instancia un objeto y mueren con él. Y a diferencia de las anteriores el valor que toman es individual para cada objeto instanciado.

En `php` la forma de hacer referencia a una variable de objeto  es con `->` y para las variables de clase (que son las definidas como `static`) con el nombre de la clase y `::`, o dentro de la misma clase como `self::` dado que ese `self` hace referencia a la clase misma.

Como ves ese modificador es para darle contexto a la variable a la que haces referencia por lo que no veo cómo sería posible no utilizarlo si lo que se necesita es referenciar una variable de clase.

Comment: puedes mejorar tu respuesta con ejemplos.